# How to set a filename for file templates in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to create a new file template in IntelliJ for a specific type of file needed by the framework I am using. The name of this file is always going to be `base.kt`, and I have added the file template as per this:

[image: File Templates Dialog]

This works fine for me other than the fact that everytime I right-click on a module and say 'New base.kt', it still asks me to enter a filename. For the `package-info` file template that comes pre-shipped with IntelliJ, it just creates the file without prompting this dialog:

[image: File name input dialog]

Is there a way for me to make IntelliJ always use a particular name and skip this dialog?

Comment: No, you can't have the fixed file template name.

Comment: @CrazyCoder this is a very common requirement. Atleast we need to have a provision to set default filename that gets populated in the above prompt, so user can change it if he wants to

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write #set($NAME="base")